# Different axis per category

Tags: highcharts

There are two different categories in my [stacked bar chart](http://jsfiddle.net/vbr59pgw/):

1. Mietpreise (rental price)
2. Kaufpreise (buy price)

The rental price is much less than the buy price (the rental price is barely visible), so I'd like to use two axes for the different scales. I don't know, how to tell Highcharts to use different axes on different categories. I only found code to say which axis to use for a single serie, but not for a single category:

```
{
        type: 'column',
        data: [194.1, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        name: 'Rainfall',
        yAxis: 1
 }
```

Comment: You can't - specific axis can be set only for series. For example you can split your data into separate datasets: http://jsfiddle.net/vbr59pgw/1/ (now just set  `series.color` to match colors).

Comment: @PawełFus: Thanks a lot. I would accept your answer, if you post your comment as answer.

Comment: It's obligatory to point out that this will result in a wildly misleading chart that will be essentially useless for the purpose at hand.  The best solution in such a case is usually to have two separate charts - one for buy price, one for rental price.  Otherwise your data is obfuscated and confusing no matter how many labels are applied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - specific axis can be set only for series. For example you can split your data into separate datasets: http://jsfiddle.net/vbr59pgw/1 (now just set series.color to match colors).

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Markspanne 1',
        data: [[0, 3.5,4]]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        name: 'Markspanne 1',
        data: [[1, 100,150]]
    }, {
        name: 'Empfehlung',
        data: [[0, 4,5]]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        name: 'Empfehlung',
        data: [[1, 150,300]]
    }, {
        name: 'Marktspanne 2',
        data: [[0, 5,6]]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        name: 'Marktspanne 2',
        data: [[1, 300,320]]
    }]
```